# How do you find the distance between a massive object and its certain gravitational force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, forces, gravity, newtonian-gravity

Okay so I know I might've not phrased the question very well so I will give an example to try to make sense of it:

Say we have the moon and a place in space where the moon's gravitational force is 1,000N. So how would I find the distance between these two?

[image]

Comment: Did you try plugging the number into the formula of [the law of gravitation?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation)

Answer (score 4):

If you talk about force you need another object for the force to act on. The force will depend on the mass of the second object. So, you cannot associate a force to a specific distance or vice-versa. You can have a force of 1000 N on an object on the surface of the Moon or on a different object situated far away from the Moon. There is no answer to the question as formulated.

Comment: Wouldn't it be fine if he just used the object m2 as 1kg.  So in Newton's formula it just becomes G x M/r^2  and he wants to solve for r.

Comment: Why 1kg and not 1g or 1 ton or 1 pound? The ratio between the force and m2 is constant but is not a force. It is the intensity of the gravitational field, in N/kg.

Comment: Because all measurements are done in kg.  It would not be a simple "1" if it was anything else.  Right?